# Hiding the dividing line in a fraction

Tags: equations, fractions, phantom, hide

I would like to be able to hide the dividing line in the fraction that arises from applying a command such as \dfrac.

In particular, what I would like to do is take an expression such as the following:

```
\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} + \dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}
```

and create a duplicate of it which highlights only the fs. I can use \phantom to hide other symbols that occur in the partial derivatives, but I don't know how to use it to hide the fraction bar.

Could anybody suggest a way forward?

Answer (score 2):

You could employ `array` environments, or you could define a macro called, say, `\nolinefrac` that employs the low-level `\genfrac` macro that's provided by the `amsmath` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \dfrac, \genfrac, and \text macros
\newcommand{\nolinefrac}[2]{\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}

\[
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} 
+ 
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}
\quad\text{vs.}\quad
\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
   \partial^2 f \\[0.5ex] \partial x^2
\end{array}
+
\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
   \partial^2 f \\[0.5ex] \partial y^2
\end{array}
\quad\text{vs.}\quad
\nolinefrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} 
+ 
\nolinefrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: You beat me just few minutes, I also wrote the suggestion based on `\genfrac` tag, but you won the race... :-D

Comment: Thanks for this. The third one does exactly what I want - if you drag and drop this over the first equation it completely overlaps.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using any macros? I am copying and pasting this equation into an app where macros cannot be defined.

Comment: @OGBond - You could replace `\nolinefrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}` with `\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}`, etc. For a more detailed follow-up, I suppose it might help if you provided some more information about this mysterious "app where macros cannot be defined".